# Is the sequence $a_{n}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{i}{n^2}\right)$ decreasing?

Tags: inequality, products

> let $$a_{n}=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{2}{n^2}\right)\cdots \left(1+\dfrac{n}{n^2}\right)$$
>
> since $$a_{1}=2,a_{2}=\dfrac{15}{8},a_{3}=\dfrac{1320}{729}\cdots $$

I found
$$a_{1}>a_{2}>a_{3}>\cdots$$

> I conjecture
> $\{a_{n}\}$ be monotone decreasing?

**remark:** It is well known this following limts
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{n}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)}}=e^{1/2}$$But the result seems to speculation regarding the inequality of useless,so how to prove inequality
$$a_{n}>a_{n+1},\forall n\in N^{+}$$

Comment: use that $$a_n={\frac {\Gamma  \left( {n}^{2}+n+1 \right)  \left( {n}^{-2} \right) ^{
n}}{\Gamma  \left( {n}^{2}+1 \right) }}$$

Comment: How to use this prove it? Thanks @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: @geromty Indeed, how? But do not hold your breath for explanations coming from user Graubner...

Comment: The gamma formula is not going to help much, I'm afraid. It's just a straightforward rewrite of the terms of your sequence, and not very clear at that, IMO it would be more informative with factorials. Without further insight, starting from there is no different than from your original form. Don't spend your time on it unless you keep a copy of Abramowitz & Stegun in your head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking logarithms is often helpful when dealing with products, so let's try that here too. Grouping terms in the difference of the logarithms, we obtain

$$\log a_n - \log a_{n+1}
= \sum_{k = 1}^n \Biggl(\log\biggl(1 + \frac{k}{n^2}\biggr) - \log \biggl(1 + \frac{k}{(n+1)^2}\biggr)\Biggr) - \log \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\biggr).$$

Now we want to bound the differences $\log \bigl(1 + \frac{k}{n^2}\bigr) - \log \bigl(1 + \frac{k}{(n+1)^2}\bigr)$ below, and $\log \bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\bigr)$ above in such a way that we obtain the desired inequality $\log a_n - \log a_{n+1} > 0$. We note that for $0 \leqslant x < y$ we have

$$\log (1 + y) - \log (1 + x) > \frac{y-x}{1+y}$$

by the mean value theorem. Using this for $x_k = \frac{k}{(n+1)^2},\, y_k = \frac{k}{n^2}$, we get

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^n \bigl(\log (1 + y_k) - \log (1 + x_k)\bigr)
&> \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{y_k - x_k}{1+y_k} \\
&= \biggl(\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\biggr) \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{k}{1+ y_k} \\
&= \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2}\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{y_k}{1+y_k} \\
&> \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2}\sum_{k = 1}^n \bigl(y_k - y_k^2\bigr) \\
&= \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2}\biggl(\frac{n+1}{2n} - \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}\biggr) \\
&= \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2}\biggl(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6n} - \frac{1}{2n^2} - \frac{1}{6n^3}\biggr) \\
&= \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\biggl(n + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} -\frac{5}{6n} - \frac{1}{3n^2} - \frac{1}{6n^3}\biggr) \\
&= \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\biggl((n+1) - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{5}{6n} - \frac{1}{3n^2} - \frac{1}{6n^3}\biggr),
\end{align}

and an easy verification shows that the final expression is greater than

$$\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{2(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{3(n+1)^3} > \log \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\biggr)$$

for $n \geqslant 5$.

The remaining cases are verified by hand:

$$a_1 = 2 > a_2 = \frac{15}{8} > a_3 = \frac{440}{243} > a_4 = \frac{14535}{8192} > a_5 = \frac{3420144}{1953125}.$$

So indeed the sequence $(a_n)$ is strictly decreasing.